# Javascript - Add an image to a div when it comes into view

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple div elements on a page, some are in the viewport on page load (usually only one) and others (up to 2 or 3) are below the fold.

I need to add an image to the div when it is visible to the user. I only want this to happen once per div. So if the user scrolls up/down again it is not counted.

I have checked on SO and have found solutions like this but I'm not sure how to get this to fire once the div comes into the view port. I've tried adding an event listener to the window when scrolled but haven't had much success and it doesn't count the initial div that is above the fold on page load until the page is scrolled. if the user doesn't scroll and leaves the page then I'm missing event.

Other solutions I've found all use an ID instead of a class.

My code so far based of the answer in the link is as follows

```
function Utils() {

}

Utils.prototype = {
    constructor: Utils,
    isElementInView: function (el, fullyInView) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        var elemTop = rect.top;
        var elemBottom = rect.bottom;

        // Only completely visible elements return true:
        var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
        // Partially visible elements return true:
        // isVisible = elemTop < window.innerHeight && elemBottom >= 0;
        return isVisible;
    }
};

var Utils = new Utils();

var matches = document.querySelectorAll("div.twinpine-container");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView(matches[i], false);

        if (isElementInView) {
            console.log(i + ' in view');
        } 
        else {
            console.log(i + ' out of view');
        }
    }
});
```

Preferably I'd like the solution to be vanilla js if possible.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you could provide a snippet or jsfiddle example that would be very helpful.

Comment: Try using the intersection observer API.https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there. Two problems: You need to know when `isVisible` *changes*, not just what it *is* - so you have to store the previous result and compare them. A simple way to store it is using a class on the element.

```
function checkVisibility ( element ) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemTop = rect.top;
    var elemBottom = rect.bottom;
    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    var prev = el.classList.contains('visible');
    var entered = isVisible === true && prev === false;
    var exited = isVisible === false && prev === true;
    el.classList.toggle( 'visible', isVisible );
    return { visible: isVisible, entered: entered, exited: exited };
}
```

Second, you want to check the visibility of these divs on load as well as on scroll. Just name your scroll function and call it, as well as attaching it to the scroll event.

```
function onScroll () {
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        var visibility = checkVisibility( matches[i] );
        if ( visibility.entered ) {
            console.log( 'hi' );
        }
        else if ( visibility.exited ) {
            console.log( 'bye' );
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
onScroll();
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, it works for setting the data attribute but does not fire the console.log on scroll.

Comment: Didn't test it I must admit. What if you log the `visibility` object?

Comment: Yeah It changes as you scroll. Sets visible to true or false depending on whether the div is in view. Entered only fires the first time which is fine. Exited never changes to true though.

Comment: That's weird. Can you put this in a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Oh, got it - writing to `el.dataset` coerces to string. Didn't know that. You can add/remove a class instead, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[AOS](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos) is a very light-weight library for the purpose i.e. animation on scroll and there are many in-built animation fade, fade-up etc. (detailed in the readme page in Github). You can also refer to the source code in the Github.

You can refer to the usage documentation in the Github readme page. For the purpose of doing the animation only once - the first time, you need to initialize in the following way:

```
<script>
  AOS.init({
    once: true
  });
</script>
```